# Having undefined reference to `pthread_join' error even using lpthread

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++, pthreads

I am using linux on ubuntu. However, I am having problem even using pthread and lpthread. Please help! Thank you in advance!

```
yuki@ubuntu:~/NetBeansProjects/csci212A3$ g++ Path.o Maze.o SubmitMazeSoln.o TestSubmitMazeSoln.cpp -o -lpthread
In file included from Maze.h:12:0,
             from TestSubmitMazeSoln.cpp:11:
Assignm3_Utils.h: In constructor ‘Point::Point()’:
Assignm3_Utils.h:17:19: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
Point ()    { x = NULL; y = NULL; }
               ^
Assignm3_Utils.h:17:29: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
Point ()    { x = NULL; y = NULL; }
                         ^
/tmp/ccMQbyoO.o: In function `newThread()':
TestSubmitMazeSoln.cpp:(.text+0x3ab2): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
TestSubmitMazeSoln.cpp:(.text+0x3b0a): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
TestSubmitMazeSoln.cpp:(.text+0x3b53): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
TestSubmitMazeSoln.cpp:(.text+0x3b79): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this really an accurate copy of your command line:

```
g++ Path.o Maze.o SubmitMazeSoln.o TestSubmitMazeSoln.cpp -o -lpthread
```

The `-o` option specifies the output file, and expects an argument.  As written above, this argument is `-lpthread`.  So `-lpthread` is *not* an argument (and the pthread library will not be searched); it is the name of your output file.  (And you don't really want an executable, or any file, with the name `-lpthread`; filenames which start with a `-` cause no end of problems under Unix.)

With regards to the warnings: I would guess from them that `x` and `y` in `Point` have type `int`.  `NULL` is the conventional way of specifying a null pointer, and using it as an `int` is obfuscation in the first degree.  So g++ warns.  (Of course, from C++11 on, one should prefer `nullptr` for a null pointer, rather than `NULL`.)